# Windows Media Player won't let me add album art

Tags: windows-media-player

When I go to add album art to Windows Media Player (via dragging and dropping) it won't let me. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Which version of WMP and Windows? Did it ever allow you to add album art that way, or are you just assuming it should work? (I don't use it so not sure myself.)

Answer (score 0):

You must be not playing the songs which are in the album you are trying to update at that moment. Restart WMP(without playing anything), go to the Album view in the Music navigation menu in the leftmost panel and then drag and drop a picture on the desired album.